# Use client-request-properties with Kql magic

Tags: kql, kqlmagic

I'm trying to run a kusto query in Jupyter using Kql magic version `0.1.114.post16`. I would like to remove the 500k lines limit and I think that the `notruncate` option listed when running `%kql --help "client-request-properties"` should solve my problem, but I can't figure out how to insert it in kql magic. It doesn't work as other options or commands.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of solved this, even though I'm not sure whether this is the correct way to use Kql magic. I just added `set notruncation;` at the top of my query, like so

```
%%kql
set notruncation;
...
```

I'd like to have the `--help` specify a bit better that these are not options of the `Kqlmagic` commands but rather have to be put inside the query.